# Kernel version name is repeated twice

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling

I'm compiling my own kernel on Ubuntu. I use

`make deb-pkg -j5`

to compile and package the kernel. In the kernel Makefile, I have added "-mykernel" to the extraversion part of the version string. However, for some reason, the version string is appended twice to the name of the kernel. Like this:
`3.17.0-mykernel-00001-ge71504dc_3.17.0-mykernel-00001-ge71504dc-2_amd64`

I want the version string to appear only once in the kernel name (i.e. `3.17.0-mykernel-00001-ge71504dc`). How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you remind me where `make deb-pkg` comes from? The recommended way to build kernels currently is, I think, what the Debian kernel devs use. See the Debian Kernel Handbook.

Comment: I have not tried installing this kernel yet. However, my past experience is that the name of the .deb package corresponds to the name of the kernel when using `make deb-pkg`. `make deb-pkg` comes from the Debian handbook. I believe this is the modern way of building and packaging the kernel on Debian systems.